# Best practice to safely load image from url

Tags: error-handling, swift2

I have the following code snippet to load an image from an url:

```
let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

In case that my variable `imageUrl` has a valid string value, what is the most secure way to protect this code against possible edge cases?

Following code seems not to be very handy:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            // success -> do something with the image...
        }
        else {
            // print error message
        }
    }
    else {
        // print error message
    }
}
else {
    // print error message
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is **not** to use a synchronous method like `contentsOfURL` to load data from over the network.

The recommended way is `NSURLSession` which works asynchronously.

This is a simple example with a completion block and an enum with associated types,
it catches all possible errors

```
enum Result {
  case Success(UIImage), Failure(NSString)
}

func loadImage(string : String, completion: (Result) -> ()) {
  guard let url = NSURL(string: string) else {
    completion(.Failure("Bad URL"))
    return
  }
  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      completion(.Failure(error!.localizedDescription))
    } else {
      guard let image = UIImage(data: data!) else {
        completion(.Failure("Could not load image data"))
        return
      }
      completion(.Success(image))
    }
  }.resume()
}
```

Call it with:

```
loadImage("http://myserver.com/path/to/image.png") { result in
  switch result {
  case .Success(let image) :
    // do something with the image
  case .Failure(let error) :
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: You´re right with the fact of asynchronous requests. But in fact your posting does not answer my exact question...